# Why are there so many "low quality posts" from people with a lot of reputation/badges/experience?

Tags: discussion, review, low-quality-posts

I just had this low quality post review https://math.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/433324 and I've been noticing a theme. This answer is a great hint, the user has a long history of great posts, but it ended up here anyway. I've noticed this is a very common theme. Why is this so? Who are flagging these posts?

Comment: The answer is very short, only 150 characters. This is probably the explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The system sometimes autofills the queue with posts that meet some requirements. It seems likely to me that this post made it to the low-quality queue because it is so short.

Comment: It should be pointed that while reviewing, it should tell you if this is an auto-flag or someone manually flagged it.

Comment: @AsafKaragila that would be nice. That is not the current behaviour, right?

Comment: Isn't it? I recall that it is.

Comment: @AsafKaragila it might be. I infrequently review since mod votes there are still binding and get tired of hitting 'skip.' I delete lots of posts already.

Comment: How touching! "The mod who couldn't delete" would be the first of its kind in internet dramas.